# Is it possible create a base image from a file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

repo with a few services and in each service, I have the following base code:

```
FROM python:3.8.13-slim-bullseye

WORKDIR /usr/app

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential -y

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pipenv setuptools
```

This is a little slow to rebuild each time, and sometimes I need to drop all images, so the idea is to know if is possible, to create Dockerfile as a base image and import this from another docker file in order to build these steps only one time locally.

Thanks

Comment: You can build an image `FROM` whatever other image you want, including one you've built locally.

Comment: But can I use FROM file?

Comment: You need to `docker build -t base-image-name .` the base image, and then your derived images can be built `FROM base-image-name`.  You can't directly refer to another Dockerfile.

Comment: ok, thanks, I guess inherithance of the code is not possible too right?

Comment: Why not?  Anything that's in the `FROM` image will be inherited into the derived image.  (There is one corner case around `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`.)

Comment: If the only thing that's different between two images is the `CMD` you'll be running – they have the same base image, the same OS and language packages, and the same code – it's also possible to `docker run the-image another_command` and override just `CMD` at runtime, maybe with multiple containers running from the same image.